# Run linked package instead of installed, npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm sorry if this question kind of nooby.

I'm developing the npm package, which is already at the registry. After installing it globally, via npm install, I still want to be able to run it, after linking, with all my changes inside. But the command now points to the package, installed globally.

Is there any way to specify different names for these packages on my machine? Like alias one to myCommandProd vs myCommandDev?

Comment: I think this is a limitation of `npm` ... If you want to keep the prod command installed globally you could create a shell alias to your development version, `alias myCommandDev="/path/to/myCommand/bin"`. Otherwise I'd just use `npm link`.

Comment: @ExplosionPills, thanks. I used `npm link`, but now can't, as have installed from registry ver

Comment: but aliasing seems like a solution

Comment: @ExplosionPills, it worked for me, so you can make answer from your comment - I'll accept it